# Removing specific nested array key from request

Tags: php, laravel

I've run into a specific problem, where I need to remove specific nested array key from my request, so it doesn't store in my database. I created a Request class, and this is how I tried to accomplish this so far:

This is my data that I'm getting from request after form submit:

```
  "options" => array:2 [▼
    "product_options" => array:1 [▶]
    "additional_product_options" => array:1 [▼
      "Tenetur dolor labore" => null
    ]
  ]
```

As you can see, `additional_product_options` array has a key with an empty value, and so I want to remove this key from array completely. I tried this using both `unset()` and `array_filter()`, but I'm not getting desired result. This is how I tried it so far:

```
if(isset($this->input('options')['additional_product_options'])){
            foreach ($this->input('options')['additional_product_options'] as $key => $val){
                if(is_null($key) || is_null($val)){ //Check for null values
                    unset($this->input('options')['additional_product_options'][$key]); //Remove key from array
                }
            }
        }
```

After I dump my request with `dd($this->options())`, I'm still getting `Tenetur dolor labore` key in this array:

```
array:2 [▼
  "product_options" => array:1 [▼
    "Et sit id culpa rep" => "sdad,ads"
  ]
  "additional_product_options" => array:1 [▼
    "Tenetur dolor labore" => null
  ]
]
```

With `array_filter()`, I'm still getting the same results:

```
if(isset($this->input('options')['additional_product_options'])){
     array_filter($this->input('options')['additional_product_options']);
}
```

After dumping my data, the key is still here:

```
  "options" => array:2 [▼
    "product_options" => array:1 [▶]
    "additional_product_options" => array:1 [▼
      "Tenetur dolor labore" => null
    ]
  ]
```

In ideal case,the `Tenetur dolor labore` key would be removed completely, and `additional_product_options` array would be empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just to check `$this->input()` this is a method that returns a value.  So each time you call it then will this be a new value or does it set the value back to wherever it gets the data from?

Comment: array_filter does not remove data, it filters out data from a specific array.

Comment: @NigelRen The $this->input() actually returns all the data that was sent when the form was submitted, so it will change when the form data changes.

Comment: My point is that you don't actually store this data and manipulate the value, you constantly retrieve it and change the return from it.  Inside the `if`, something like `$options = $this->input('options')['additional_product_options'];` and then process `$options` instead.

Comment: I get what you're saying now, will try to do that instead.

Answer (score 1):

try this ... i have test it for current options array:

for test reason, i made the option array:

```
   $options = ['product_options' => ['additional_product_options' => 
['Tenetur dolor labore' => null]], 'additional_product_options' => 'some value'];
```

then

```
  unset($options['product_options']['additional_product_options']['Tenetur dolor labore']);
```

the result is removing the key as we want ...

Comment: Hmm, this will work, but I will get different `additional_product_options` keys every time I submit a new form, so this would have to be more dynamic.